# Un switch tiene direcciones mac en sus puertos?

Tags: redes, networking

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de redes, tengo una duda, un switch tiene direcciones mac en cada puerto? 
Si es así para que se usan

Comment: Los switches si tienes direcciones MAC en los puertos. Un switch necesita su propia dirección MAC si va a ser una fuente final o destinatario de una trama Ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un switch, el dispositivo tiene su dirección MAC propia, pero dependiendo del switch tendrá una dirección para cada puerto.

De hecho para que el switch pueda funcionar básicamente no necesita una dirección MAC en cada puerto y no debería pues utiliza una que aprende desde el origen de los paquetes, este caso aplica para los switches más sencillos.

En cuanto a los switches que tienen una dirección para cada puerto es porque realizan una operación más compleja que simplemente redirección de paquetes, este tipo de switches pueden realizar varios tipos de control, así como anunciamiento de VLANS, negociar canales o descubrimiento de otros switches. También se le pueden hacer telnets o pings a estos switches.

No sé si entiendes inglés pero puedes mirar este [enlace](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/what-switches-do-with-their-mac-address/td-p/2594133) donde preguntan algo parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Cada equipo cuenta con una MAC asignada, los puestos no cuentan con mac, lo que se le puede hacer es configurar mac a cada puerto para que unicamente se conecte el equipo a la cual pertenece esa mac. y que cuando otro usuario se quiera conectar a ese puerto no lo deje ya que no pertenece a la que tiene configurda.

Answer (score 0):

Los switch no tienen dirección mac en los puertos, el switch tiene su propia mac y con el comando show mac-address-table puedes observar las direcciones mac que el switch descubrió y que pertenecen a los dispositivos concectados a esos puertos, pueden ser dispositivos finales(como computadoras, servidores) o routers.